# How to delete blank DataGridView Row on Load in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a DataGridView that is bound by a datasource in VB.net Windows forms application. When I import my data into the DataGrid I want any blank or null fields to be colored in red until the user inputs data. I’ve already accomplished this but I have a slight issue. When the user adds a new blank row to the DataGrid and doesn’t  fill in any data, that newly formed row on load up will be completely colored in red, instead I want to delete this newly generated row on load. This is how I’ve gone about doing this, but I haven’t been successful. I greatly appreciate any help or suggestions you may offer.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    'Created a Boolean flag if empty
    Dim empty as Boolean = True

    Dim cellString = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value

    If cellString Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(cellString) OrElse cellString.ToString = String.Empty OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellString) = True Then
       empty = True
    Else
       empty = False
    End If
    'End If

    'create variable assigned the rowindex of the last row of the DataGridView
    Dim lastRow As String = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value        
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 OrElse e.ColumnIndex = 1 OrElse e.ColumnIndex = 2) Then
       If empty = False Then
           'If row is not empty then allow the newly generated row on load
           DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true
       Else               
           If empty = True AndAlso e.RowIndex = lastRow Then
              'If row is empty and it’s the last row then prevent the row from being added to ‘the datagridview                            
              DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False               
           Else If empty = True AndAlso e.RowIndex <> lastRow Then
              'the row is empty and not the last row then paint the cell red
              DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
           End If
        End If
     End If 
 End Sub
```

Comment: you could use a For/Each to go thru the cells to see if they are all empty

Comment: Can't you use RowValidating event to not allow to even save such row?